# QGIS Reports: Group Many Points by Attribute

Tags: qgis, reports

How is it possible to generate a report for grouped features instead of one feature per page?

Imagine a data set of 300 points, the points are clustered into 30 groups. It is not possible to generate a report with 30 pages, each page including one cluster.
Instead, QGIS outputs 300 pages.

This does not work.

Comment: Creating an atlas based on the groups would be an option? Do you have an attribute for the groups? Or create a convex hull around each group, than use these polygons as coverage layer for atlas generation.

Comment: Yes, I have an attribute defining the groups of points. I think I will opt for the invisible convex hull option. However the generation of attribute tables becomes difficult then.